# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000b31c60 [C Language]

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, free

I'm currently building an assembler as a project and I'm on the verge of finishing it. I created  different linked-lists to implement different functions in the assembler, and now I'm trying to build 'free()' functions for each and every linked-list I created. Here is the node structure:

```
typedef struct symbol_node_t
{
    struct symbol_node_t* next; /* the next node in the linked-list */
    char            name[32]; /* name of the node */
    int             value; /* address (either Instruction counter or Data counter) */
    enum symbol_attributes attr; /* CODE/DATA/ENTRY/EXTERNAL */

} symbol_node_t;
```

now, I created global heads:

```
struct symbol_node_t* symbol_head = NULL; /* this is the head of one linked-list */
struct symbol_node_t* external_head = NULL; /* this is the head of a different linked-list */
```

then, implemented them throughout the whole project. I wrote free() function for the first linked-list ('symbol_head' linked-list) which works well, here it is:

```
void free_symbols()
{
  while(symbol_head != NULL)
   {
    free(symbol_head);
    symbol_head = symbol_head->next;
   }
}
```

but for a very odd reason, the same function for 'external_head' doesn't work:

```
void free_externals()
{
    while(external_head != NULL)
    {
        free(external_head);
        external_head = external_head->next;
    }
}
```

whenever it gets there - it writes the following error message:

```
[SYMBOL TABLE]
name[END]        value[148]      sym_attributes[CODE] has_next[1]
name[K]          value[161]      sym_attributes[DATA, ENTRY] has_next[1]
name[val1]       value[0]        sym_attributes[EXTERNAL] has_next[1]
name[LIST]       value[157]      sym_attributes[DATA] has_next[1]
name[Next]       value[116]      sym_attributes[CODE, ENTRY] has_next[1]
name[LOOP]       value[104]      sym_attributes[CODE] has_next[1]
name[MAIN]       value[100]      sym_attributes[CODE] has_next[1]
name[STR]        value[152]      sym_attributes[DATA] has_next[1]
name[wNumber]    value[0]        sym_attributes[EXTERNAL] has_next[0]
symbols size: 9
*** Error in `./asm': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000b31c60 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777f5)[0x7f8c7aaa77f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1a8)[0x7f8c7aab46e8]
./asm[0x403183]
./asm[0x400e72]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f8c7aa50840]
./asm[0x400a59]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 396017                     /home/chad/asm/asm
00404000-00405000 r-xp 00004000 00:00 396017                     /home/chad/asm/asm
00604000-00605000 r--p 00004000 00:00 396017                     /home/chad/asm/asm
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 00:00 396017                     /home/chad/asm/asm
00b30000-00b51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f8c7a810000-7f8c7a826000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 159188             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8c7a826000-7f8c7aa25000 ---p 00016000 00:00 159188             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8c7aa25000-7f8c7aa26000 rw-p 00015000 00:00 159188             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8c7aa30000-7f8c7abf0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 204371             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f8c7abf0000-7f8c7abf9000 ---p 001c0000 00:00 204371             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
```

From what I understand, the issue is with the pointer, but it is weird that 2 of these heads are implemented in the same way, yet in symbol_head, it works perfectly fine and in external_head, it just gives this error. Can you help me out finding what could be the issue here please? I thank you all in advance!

Comment: You first free and then try to use the memory. Reverse that: first read from the memory (next) into a temporary, then free, then assign `external_head = next_read_previously`. Same issue for symbol free-ing, it's just that you were 'lucky' and the error didn't show.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't quite get that.. Are you trying to say that I need to something like this: create a temporary_node that will handle external_head , and then i will free(external_head) and assign temporary_node = temporary_node-> next , and then external_head = temporary_node ?

Comment: Almost. You need to store the next. `next = external_head->next; free(external_head); external_head = next;`

Answer (score 0):

Right now `free_symbols` and `free_externals` first call `free` and then dereference the free'd object, making your program have *undefined behavior*. You need to first  get the `next` pointer, then `free`.

Example:

```
void symbol_node_free(symbol_node_t** head_ptr) {    
    for(symbol_node_t* next; *head_ptr; *head_ptr = next) {
        next = (*head_ptr)->next;
        free(*head_ptr);
    }
}

void free_symbols() { symbol_node_free(&symbol_head); }
void free_externals() { symbol_node_free(&external_head); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your free functions are subject to undefined behavior, because they attempt to access fields of structures after those structures have been freed.  For example, `free_symbols` looks like this:

```
void free_symbols()
{
  while(symbol_head != NULL)
   {
    free(symbol_head);
    symbol_head = symbol_head->next;
   }
}
```

After the call to `free`, `symbol_head` points to freed memory whose contents are undefined, so the reference `symbol_head->next` is subject to undefined behavior.

To fix it, save the `next` field *before* freeing the structure:

```
void free_symbols(void)
{
  while(symbol_head != NULL)
   {
    struct symbol_node_t *next = symbol_head->next;
    free(symbol_head);
    symbol_head = next;
   }
}
```

The same change is needed in `free_externals`:

```
void free_externals(void)
{
    while(external_head != NULL)
    {
        struct symbol_node_t *next = external_head->next;
        free(external_head);
        external_head = next;
    }
}
```